# Is it possible to implement an snmp trap receiver using SNMP4J in a Java EE environment?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, snmp4j

I'm trying to implement an SNMP trap reciever that will be deployed as part of a service that runs on a Payara 5 server, but it appears to require the use of `org.snmp4j.util.MultiThreadedMessageDispatcher`and `org.snmp4j.util.ThreadPool`. I'm looking for a way to implement this without having to spawn my own threads. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to work around the old "thou shalt not create threads in EJBs" problem?

Comment: Yes, essentially that is my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys to your problem are in the [javax.enterprise.concurrent](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. This provides mandated support for thread creation and management, even from EJBs. It is provided as part of the Java EE 7 and newer platforms, including Payara 5.

You will need to provide your own implementation of [org.snmp4j.util.WorkerPool](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/util/WorkerPool.html) which would be built on top of the `javax.enterprise.concurrent` package.

If you enjoy programming for a living this would be the fun part.